# inserting multiple(many ) rows into table in one time

Tags: mysql

how to inset into mysql table,example `INSERT INTO users(user_id,time,)VALUES(1-500,1524275145)` in my case need insert into TABLE users 500 rows form 1-500(it's users id) with same values `time` for all users.

Comment: aha thanks, I need search mysql loop

Comment: The loop is supposed to be created on code in another language, like JavaScript, in the browser console: for (i=0; i <500, i++) { query+='('+i+', 1524275145),'} to simplify...

Comment: You have only tagged mysql and you haven't said where this data is comong from so impossible to advise you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried this one, it is working:

First you execute this snippet to create a procedure in your database so that we can call it later (the second snippet) and execute the query that will insert the 1-500 values into the `users` `user_id` column. (You can see the two variables that have values of `500` and `1`, and you can see the line: `VALUES (user_id_val, 1524275145)` where the query will be executed.)

**First snippet:** (try to execute it separately from the next one)

```
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS insert_loop;

DELIMITER # 
CREATE PROCEDURE insert_loop() 
BEGIN 
    DECLARE user_id_max INT UNSIGNED DEFAULT 500;
    DECLARE user_id_val INT UNSIGNED DEFAULT 1;
    START transaction;
        WHILE user_id_val < user_id_max+1 DO
            INSERT INTO users (user_id, time) 
            VALUES (user_id_val, 1524275145);
            SET user_id_val = user_id_val + 1;
        END WHILE;
    COMMIT;
END #
```

**Second snippet:**

```
DELIMITER ;
CALL insert_loop();
```

Execute this after the first one (separately).

Answer (score 0):

An example query for your case would be like this:

```
 INSERT INTO users (user_id,time) VALUES
 (1, 1524275145),
 (2, 1524275145),
 (3, 1524275145),
 (4, 1524275145);
```

And so on, until 500. The best approach would be to create the query in a for loop.